# Can you help me with my homework?

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, computer-science

My teacher set me some homework:

[image]

What is the answer to my homework?

---

You will also **need** a [copy of my homework](http://pastebin.com/raw/v7Pa6ewr) to help you.

You don't need the image to solve the puzzle, that is just a preview.

Hint:

> The question is from my computer science teacher, who has been experimenting with some strange programming languages...

After solving

> I couldn't write the text out on SE because it doesn't allow tabs.

Comment: Is this legitimately your homework?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil no

Comment: Good. Just had to ask. And if  it was, then I would definitely be wondering what sort of school you go to :P

Comment: @Melkor Why an image? could you write it out instead?

Comment: Shame I can't access pastebin links.

Comment: @LeppyR64 The text in the paste is exactly the same as in the image with 4 spaces on blank lines and `17 12 16 16 9 18 15 12 24 21 18 0` spaces after the non-blank lines.

Comment: @dcfyj, no sorry, but it's won't work with the puzzle. You can see the text in the pastebin link.

Comment: Are there word or letter delimiters? Trial and error is painful:)

Comment: @Will: These are not all spaces; they are spaces and tabs.

Comment: I have never dealt with MC. How do you figure out where a letter ends and the next one starts?

Comment: @MOehm Wow, my text editors all hate tabs even more than I realized. Good spot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution 1:

> As M Oehm said, if you convert the spaces after the lines to 0 and the tabs as 1, you get:
>
> ```
> 0001101001
> 0000100000
> 111100
> 00110011
> 100000
> 1110011
> 1100011
> 1101000
> 1101111
> 1101111
> 1101100
> ```
>
> Converting this to ASCII, you get the message **<3 school**.

Solution 2:

> If you run this in the esoteric programming language Whitespace, you get the message **i <3 school**.
>  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/whitespace#TZExUsMwEEVr5xR/0tAwvkMAARnAReKZ1Eq8jgSyBNI6jjsOwum4SJBkD6CxtrD///t2ffn@/HpZPa2rB6yre7ER1a3YLgEUBYpYF8ViI1Z36fuNqHdCVKgfBZ7XldgiyVJBVO28ZvIBrmWyaBysY9D53UhtQSfyIyttj2AHVlTEk22eZEO@xNZhdD26PjCW6SX2xAPFqKiG0ZbCMkPFm5iyLaD19NGTZTPCEjUpvdW2QeikMTiYnkIMkPyLaVJ0jOySVNuWPDLXJJvR5iayZ@V8nIWCvZqG0QedegWWTCVqRb99k2uy9YFSsvOdZO1sZHRdnoLpzKntMVKFclpwYqqVDojPoEb4eTAlT5S0xrm3pCwmIs5rfU1bGmZezJiZKVz/ifc9z3CKtIcbbDQ2R@rivuJvygFZnSH@JXUkbSgvlx8)

Comment: Well done to @Oliver and @M Oehm!